# Importing an excel column of lists with pandas

Tags: pandas

I have an excel file with a column that contains lists (see image). What is the correct way to use pandas.read_excel() in order to import the column?

[image: excel screenshot]

I ultimately need to be able create a dataframe with a column for each value of the list.

This is what I thought I would need to do but it is not correct.

```
# read in the file
df = pd.read_excel('fruit.xlsx')
df

# this isn't working...
# create new dataframe with column for each value of the "Fruit" column in df
fruits = df['Fruit'].apply(pd.Series)
fruits
```

The following does work though when I create the initial dataframe from a dictionary rather than reading in an excel file.

What am I doing wrong with read_excel()?
How do I specify that the excel column is lists?

```
# dictionary with the same data as the excel file
raw_data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'Fruit': [['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear'],
                      ['Pineapple'],
                      '',
                      ['Apple', 'Orange']]}

# dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['ID', 'Fruit'])
df

# new dataframe with a column for each value of the lists
fruits = df['Fruit'].apply(pd.Series)
fruits
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can do `df['Fruit']=df['Fruit'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` after importing from excel, then do `df=df[['ID']].join(pd.DataFrame(df.Fruit.values.tolist()))` , dont use `apply(pd.Series)` , it is slow

Comment: Thanks. That works. I did have to dropna() from the dataframe prior to apply(ast.literal_eval).